# Drush site upgrade: Contributed extensions were not upgaraded

Tags: 7, drush, upgrading

I am using [Drush site upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_sup) module for D6 to D7 Upgrade.

In step 15, drush asks me to update only one module i.e. path_access, and for all the modules it says "following contributed extensions were not upgaraded". Then in final step its says "there are no more modules to be upgraded".
And my all contributed modules remained unupgraded.
Should I need to upgrade them manually.

Comment: This is a beta module, that means it is perfectly normal it will fail sometimes. And there are bugs open for more than a year, [request for proper documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1703034) is over 2 years old if I see correctly. Also, it seems what you ask [may be aplready answered in community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/948216).

Comment: thanks @Mołot Yes its in Beta, but its happened only to me as there is no such issue in issue queue. And I know about https://www.drupal.org/node/948216 but this should be expected to done by this module, thats why I am asking.

Comment: It looks like a bug, and module is dead. Maintenance status: Seeking new maintainer; Development status: No further development. Rule of thumb - don't use dead modules unless you can edit their code on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should [Migrate d2d](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module for content migration and also should upgrade contributed modules manually as might be some modules aren't supported in drupal 7. So, this should be a manual task. But using [Migrate d2d](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module, you should be able to migrate content :).

I guess this is helpful to you.